# Visualize mesh in 2d plot / projection (gnuplot)

Tags: 3d, grid, 2d, gnuplot

In my simulations, I have two numerical grids that overlap each other. One of them (the smaller one) is not rectangular but has a curved boundary (at least the area in which I care about it).

I would like to visualize those two numerical grids and how they overlap each other in gnuplot as a 2D plot. The result should look similar to this:

[image]

The red grid spans the entire area, the black grid is a subset of the red one with a curved boundary. The blue line is an approximation of the boundary.

This looks good so far, except for the fact that this is a 3D-plot at which I look exactly from above; i.e. in gnuplot I can rotate it if I wanted to.

```
gnuplot> show view
    view is 0 rot_x, 270 rot_z, 1 scale, 1 scale_z
```

Viewed from this angle none of the information of the z-axis is visible. It sort of removes the reason for a 3D plot as all you can see are the grids on which your data live. And this is precisely what I want.

But then, I rather have a 2D plot since those are more efficient to handle in gnuplot and also gnuplot generates a huge margin around 3D plots which reduces the useable area. How can I get this mesh projected into a 2D plane and get gnuplot to visualise it?

---

How to create above plot:
I have one variable that is defined on the entire grid, but is non-zero (and always positive) only on the black part of the grid. The data are stored in the file "values.dat" in the usual way---in three columns in polar coordinates:

r (radius) -- theta (polar angle) -- value

Then you can get above plot with:

```
set style line 1 lt 1 dt 3 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "black"
set view 0, 270, 1, 1
splot "values.dat" u 1:2:(1.0) w l ls 1, \
      "values.dat" u 1:2:($3>0.0?1.0:NaN) w l ls 2
```

The blue line in the graph is additional and comes from a separate approximation of the grid boundary but is not really relevant for the question here.

Comment: you did this graph in gnuplot? Where is the code for generating this plot? How does the data for the grid spacing look like?

Comment: @theozh, I've added a section to my question, explaining the data structure and the gnuplot commands.

Comment: I just figured that the `set view map` command in gnuplot did exactly what I want! Success!

Answer (score 0):

The gnuplot command

```
set view map
```

does exactly what I want.

From the gnuplot documentation:

> It supports both 3D projection or orthogonal 2D projection into a 2D plot-like map.